# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/netanelb/www/Admin/confClicks.php on line 333

```
 foreach ($a as $key => $value1) 
        {
            $mil = $value1['latestDate'];

            $seconds = $mil / 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

It means just that — `$a` isn't an array, so `foreach` can't be applied to it.

Try using `var_dump($a)` before your `foreach` and you'll see that it is not a loop.